# Not Able to Install & Run Script During Terraform Install using Remote-Exec

Tags: terraform

I am trying to install and run Tailscale during a terraform install (I do not think this is a tailscale related issue, just as an example.

The resource.tf file is here:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami                    = var.instance_ami
  instance_type          = var.instance_type
  subnet_id              = var.subnet_public_id
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.security_group_ids
  key_name               = var.key_pair_name
  availability_zone      = var.availability_zone

  tags = {
    App  = var.app_tag
    Name = "${var.app_tag}-instance"
  }

  // Move all files from scripts to the remote instance in the /node directory
  provisioner "file" {
    connection {
      host        = self.public_dns
      port        = 22
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = var.private_key_content
    }

    source      = "node_files"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/node_files"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      host        = self.public_dns
      port        = 22
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = var.private_key_content
    }

    inline = [
      "sudo mkdir /node",
      "sudo mv /home/ubuntu/node_files/* /node",
      "sudo rm -rf /home/ubuntu/node_files",
      "sudo chmod +x /node/*.sh",
      "sudo mkdir /data",
      "sudo mv /node/bacalhau.service /etc/systemd/system",
      "echo \"$USER ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL\" | sudo tee \"/etc/sudoers.d/dont-prompt-$USER-for-sudo-password\"",
      "sudo mv /node/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config",
      "sudo systemctl restart sshd",
      "echo 0",
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "instanceeip" {
  vpc      = true
  instance = aws_instance.instance.id

  tags = {
    App = var.app_tag
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "copy-to-node-if-worker" {
  count = var.bootstrap_region == var.region ? 0 : 1

  connection {
    host        = aws_eip.instanceeip.public_ip
    port        = 22
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = var.private_key_content
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    destination = "/etc/bacalhau-bootstrap"
    content     = file(var.bacalhau_run_file)
  }
}


resource "null_resource" "install_tailscale_and_join" {
  depends_on = [aws_instance.instance, null_resource.copy-to-node-if-worker]

  connection {
    host        = aws_instance.instance.public_dns
    port        = 22
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = var.private_key_content
    timeout     = 600
  }

  // Run the commands in the remote instance to install_tailscale.sh, install_bacalhau.sh, and restart the bacalhau service
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo chmod +x /node/install-tailscale.sh",
      "sudo /node/install-tailscale.sh ${aws_instance.instance.public_dns}",
      "sudo tailscale up",
      "echo 0",
    ]

  }
}
```

I've tried it many times, and it fails - reliably - at the last step with the following error.

```
[... many lines above ...]
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join: Provisioning with 'remote-exec'...
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join (remote-exec):   Host: ec2-35-182-12-176.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join (remote-exec):   User: ubuntu
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join (remote-exec):   Password: false
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join (remote-exec):   Private key: true
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: true
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join (remote-exec):   Target Platform: unix
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join (remote-exec): Connected!
module.instanceModule.aws_eip.instanceeip: Creation complete after 1s [id=eipalloc-0b50a293c13823180]
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: remote-exec provisioner error
│
│   with module.instanceModule.null_resource.install_tailscale_and_join,
│   on modules/instance/resources.tf line 88, in resource "null_resource" "install_tailscale_and_join":
│   88:   provisioner "remote-exec" {
│
│ Error starting script: EOF
```

Terraform recommends against using remote-exec/provisioners and instead using Packer, but due to the nature of this deployment, I would prefer to do these installations in this way.

The closest research I got to was here -https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18517 - which feels correct, but adding the keep alive did not seem to help at all.

Not sure what to do at this point - the script runs fine, this is provable when I log in.

Comment: The other available recommendation for what to do instead of provisioners is to use an AMI with CloudInit installed and [use your platform's "user data" (or similar) mechanism to pass configuration to it](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#passing-data-into-virtual-machines-and-other-compute-resources). Is that also not a suitable solution for your situation?

Comment: i'm trying that out now!